# Failed GET request in AJAX/DJANGO framework

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, django

```
$('#searchButton').click(function() {
    var keywords_list = [];
    $('#selectedKeywords option').each(function() {
        keywords_list.push($(this).text());
    });
    $.ajax({
        url: '/website/general_keyword_search',
        type: 'GET',
        data: {database_name: {{ database_name }}, keywords: keywords_list},
        success: function(data) {
            alert('Works');
        },
        failure: function(data) {
            alert('Nope');
        },
        error: function(xhr, status, errorThrown) {
            alert('Problem');
            console.log('Error: '+errorThrown);
            console.log('Status: '+status);
            console.dir(xhr);
        },
        complete: function() {
            alert('Completed');
        }
    });
});
```

This is the code I'm trying to run, but when I click on the 'searchButton' nothing happens, not even an error message. I've tested it to make sure that everything works just before the ajax script. What I'm basically trying to do here is that I'm picking up words from a 'select-list', storing them in an array (which is working fine) and throwing it at my Django backend, which would process it and return a different list of objects. Any help would be appreciated.

P.S. I'm using JQuery 2.1.1.

Comment: I'm guessing the `{{ database_name }}` is part of a template or something?  Otherwise, your js has a syntax-error and nothing will happen anywhere ;-)

Comment: see console errors...

Comment: Yes, it is returned as a part of context_dictionary by the backend.

Comment: I get errno32, broken pipeline. But that happened only twice. On other occasions, just nothing. :/